# App Engine - Deploy new version error 500 (due to session)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When i deploy a new version to App Engine the session of the user will still active, so if some change appended in the session objects then an error 500 will be triggered.

So to fix that i have to remove my cookies with the jsessionid.

I'm looking for a way to log off all the users if a new version is deployed, just like if you will do it in the development environment in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is to have the new version of the code check the session and verify it's the new session, otherwise, fail gracefully and reset the session object.

Comment: I should put the version number in session when the user logged in then, right? I'm surprise that there is not easy way to deal with this :/

Comment: By the way... Is there a way to access the version number in your java code?

Comment: On python, I'd inspect the session object to see if it is missing a new attribute, rather than an explicit version number.  This might be a bit harder in Java.  The version numbering still works.  Check this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty